# Class basics (instances) - python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am posting two pieces of code, the first has two instances:

```
class student:
    def display_name(self, name):
        print "student name is ", name
    def class_room(self, standard):
        print "Student Section is ", standard

instance1 = student()
instance2 = student()

instance1.display_name('Tom')
instance1.class_room('12th "B"')
instance2.display_name('Dick')
instance2.class_room('11th "B"')
```

The second has one instance:

```
class student:
    def display_name(self, name):
        print "student name is ", name
    def class_room(self, standard):
        print "Student Section is ", standard

instance1 = student()

instance1.display_name('Tom')
instance1.class_room('12th "B"')
instance1.display_name('Dick')
instance1.class_room('11th "B"')
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Both has **same result**

Comment: What are you expecting as output?

Comment: First you got 2 class: Tom inside and  Dick inside. Second you got 1 class all persons inside. But you not save any data (wrong question!)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding the use of classes. In your example, your class instances essentially have no state. Those function don't make any use of their `self` argument, and may as well be static class methods. That's why your two examples will produce the same output, they're independent of which instance they're called from.

Typically you would have attributes of the class that each instance of the class could set. Then in the various methods, you can access those attributes off the `self` instance. For example

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, standard):
        self.name = name
        self.standard = standard
    def display_name(self):
        return 'student name is {}'.format(self.name)
    def class_room(self):
        return 'student section is {}'.format(self.standard)
```

Now you can make two instances

```
>>> instance1 = Student('Tom', '12th B')
>>> instance2 = Student('Dick', '11th B')
```

Now you can call the methods off of those instances, and it will use their attributes

```
>>> instance1.display_name()
'student name is Tom'
>>> instance2.display_name()
'student name is Dick'
>>> instance1.class_room()
'student section is 12th B'
>>> instance2.class_room()
'student section is 11th B'
```